# HTML5 meter tag not working in IE10

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using html5 meter tag it's working fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.
is there any solution apart from Progress bar?
please let me know thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, no stable version of Internet Explorer supports the meter element.
Even the Modernizr test suite failed to detect meter in IE10 / IE11 on Windows 8.1.
This perhaps leaves you only with the fallback approaches.

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/793736/ie11-feature-request-support-for-meter

Comment: So for me only one option I have to go for Progress bar right?

Comment: Yes, until MS fixes their "browser".

Comment: @OuSs haha, you're too funny! (Re: fixing their browser)